# C# array from text files with specific values

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, count

I have this file called failas.txt. It contains text in Lithuanian language. I did Encoding 1257 for it so it can read Lithuanian letters.

Now all I have to do is to make an array for each Lithuanian letter used in that file.

All those letters are in string `p = "AĄBCČDEĘĖFGHIĮYJKLMNOPRSŠTUŲŪVZŽ";`

Array should show how many times each letter is repeated in a text and write those results to a new txt file called rezultatai.txt. So the code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO; skirta biblioteka
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
class Program 
{
static void Main()
    {

    string failas = "failas.txt"; 
    string rodymas = File.ReadAllText(failas, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257)); 
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Console.WriteLine(rodymas); 
    char[] masyvas = rodymas.Where(Char.IsLetter).OrderBy(Char.ToLower).ToArray(); 
    foreach (char c in masyvas)

    {
        Console.Write(c + ",");
    }
    string p = "AĄBCČDEĘĖFGHIĮYJKLMNOPRSŠTUŲŪVZŽ";
    failas = failas.ToUpper();
    Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    foreach (char c in p) dict.Add(c, 0);
    foreach (char c in failas)
    {
        int val;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(c, out val)) dict[c] = val + 1;
    }

    //write to a file..
    foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> item in dict)
    {
        if (item.Value > 0) Console.WriteLine("Character {0}, No of Occurences = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
        File.AppendAllText("rezultatai.txt", item.Value + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0}", dict.Sum(x => x.Value));
    Console.ReadKey();
```

However, somehow it returns only output with letters A, F, I, L, S, T. Like this:

```
Character A, No of Occurences = 2
Character F, No of Occurences = 1
Character I, No of Occurences = 1
Character L, No of Occurences = 1
Character S, No of Occurences = 1
Character T, No of Occurences = 2
```

As I mentioned before, letters should be:

`AĄBCČDEĘĖFGHIĮYJKLMNOPRSŠTUŲŪVZŽ`

Also, when I open **rezultatai.txt** file to check appended values,  it only contains a long column of numbers:

```
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
2
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, somehow it returns only output with letters A, F, I, L, S, T. Like this:

```
foreach (char c in failas)
```

You iterate over the *filename*, which is `"failas.txt"`, This should be the actual file's text.

```
foreach (char c in rodymas)
foreach (char c in masyvas)  // Possibly the char array.. not sure which..
```

> Also, when I open rezultatai.txt file to check appended values, it only contains a long column of numbers:

Yes, you append the value from a `KeyValuePair` where the value is an integer, this presumably needs to be the same as what you output to the console.

Comment: I think I found the actual problem, but it only takes letters which are Uppercase. How to make it take both uppercase and lowercase?

Comment: @SocketChecker - That appears to be a different issue unrelated to this question

Answer (score 1):

.NET has pretty powerful features, like LINQ and the CultureInfo system. You can use both to do this in a few lines:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

internal class Program
{
  private static void Main()
  {
    var cultureLithunia = new CultureInfo("lt-LT");
    var textInfoLithunia = cultureLithunia.TextInfo;

    string requested = textInfoLithunia.ToUpper("AĄBCČDEĘĖFGHIĮYJKLMNOPRSŠTUŲŪVZŽ");

    string content = File.ReadAllText("failas.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(textInfoLithunia.ANSICodePage));

    var characters = content.GroupBy(c => c);

    var charactersYouWant = characters.Where(c => requested.Contains(textInfoLithunia.ToUpper(c.Key)));

    var linesYouWantToOutput = charactersYouWant.Select(c => string.Format("Character {0}, No of Occurences = {1}", c.Key, c.Count()));

    File.WriteAllLines("rezultatai.txt", linesYouWantToOutput);

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

If you want all characters from the required text, it's a bit more complicated:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

internal class Program
{
  private static void Main()
  {
    var cultureLithunia = new CultureInfo("lt-LT");
    var textInfoLithunia = cultureLithunia.TextInfo;

    string requested = textInfoLithunia.ToUpper("AĄBCČDEĘĖFGHIĮYJKLMNOPRSŠTUŲŪVZŽ");

    string content = File.ReadAllText("failas.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(textInfoLithunia.ANSICodePage));

    var characters = content.GroupBy(c => c);

    var charactersYouWant = requested.Select(c => new { Key = c, Count = characters.Where(cc => textInfoLithunia.ToUpper(cc.Key) == c).Select(group => group.Count()).FirstOrDefault() });

    var linesYouWantToOutput = charactersYouWant.Select(c => string.Format("Character {0}, No of Occurences = {1}", c.Key, c.Count));

    File.WriteAllLines("rezultatai.txt", linesYouWantToOutput);

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Comment: this is great! but it doesn't include letters that is used 0 times. any way to do it?

Comment: @SocketChecker I put in a second version. I don't have data to test it, you should test it yourself.